# Update value on header after Subject change

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular5

I'm working on a notification feature on a Angular 5 project. There's a property on header called `notifications` storing number of new notifications for that user.

I want to dynamically update that `notifications` property on header after a call from another component, which means I will decrease it every time a user clicks on 'seen' button. But even though the header component is set to be subscribed at a change on notification service's Subject, the `notifications` value is not changing.

This is a extract from `notification.service.ts`

```js
export class NotificationService {
    notifications: any;
    public notificationChange: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){

        this.notificationChange.subscribe((value) => {
            this.notificationNumber = value;
        });
    }

    updateNotificationNumber(item: any) {   
        this.notificationChange.next(item);
    }
}
```

On my `notification.component.ts`, there's this function `updateNotificationToSeen` called after a button click (the number sent is hardcoded just for testing purposes. I will eventually make it right after I can see effective changes) that triggers the `updateNotificationNumber` from service.

```js
export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService){}

    updateNotificationToSeen() {
        this.notificationService.updateNotificationNumber(150); 
    }
}
```

This is a extract from `header.component.ts`, which I tried to subscribe the notificationChange on its `constructor`, but it did not work. I also tried the way is listed below, on `ngOnInit` but again, no changes.

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    notifications: number;

    constructor(public notificationService: NotificationService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(){
         this.notificationService.notificationChange.subscribe(value =>{
            this.notifications = value;
        })
    }

}
```

I've tried a few tutorials but I couldn't figure out why header can't see changes after that property.

I will appreciate any thoughts on a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging it like so:

NotificationComponent

```
updateNotificationToSeen() {
        console.log('Notification Component: updating notification number');
        this.notificationService.updateNotificationNumber(150); 
    }
```

NotificationService

```
updateNotificationNumber(item: any) { 
        console.log('Notification Service: update notification number, calling next');  
        this.notificationChange.next(item);
    }
```

HeaderComponent

```
ngOnInit(){
         this.notificationService.notificationChange.subscribe(value =>{
            console.log('HeaderComponent: Getting value');
            this.notifications = value;
        })
    }
```

Make sure you get

`Notification Component: updating notification number`
`Notification Service: update notification number, calling next`
`HeaderComponent: Getting value`

in that order.

If you don't get that, and one of them doesn't log, then it's most likely a culprit. See why it doesn't log.

Comment: Thanks, but in fact I have tried this debugging, too. I just didn't mentioned in problem description all the console.logs to make code cleaner. Well, thing is the debug in header.component.ts is never shown. That's when I came here to find a clue why is that. I'm looking for docs to check component's lifecycle to see if there's any indication of a proper way to do the header property update.

Comment: Is your notification service global? Provided in one module?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Observables here... In the service do as follows:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {
    private notificationsSubject: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null);
    public notifications$ = this.notificationsSubject.asObservable();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    public updateNotifications(value: number): void {
        this.notificationsSubject.next(value);
    }
}
```

BehaviorSubject stores the current value, so its more relevant for your particular case. Also keep in mind that your service must be a singleton (`providedIn: 'root'` ensures that)

Now in your component you need to inject this service.
So, you can subscirbe to notifications$ observable anywhere and get its current value, as well as to emit new values via calling public method `updateNotifications()`

So you component looks as follows:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    public notifications$: Observable<number>;

    constructor(public notificationService: NotificationService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
         this.notifications$ = this.notificationService.notifications$
    }
}
```

Using [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in a template helps you with unsubscription handling...

Thus header template will look as follows:

```
<div>{{ notifications$ | async }}</div>

//or

<ng-container *ngIf="notifications$ | async as notifications">
  <div >{{ notifications }}</div>
</ng-container>
```

As a result... Whenever subjects emits new value, all subscribed components values will be updated immediatelly.

Comment: This is not working since my app is a Angular 5. The Injectable 'providedIn' : 'root' is a Angular 6 feature

Comment: You simply need to inhect this service into the root module, which is appModule, I assume, and it will be defined singleton